# Where does orbeon form saved?

Tags: forms, exists, orbeon, xforms

I am a new user of orbeon and am trying to some exercise with orbeon's code. I have downloaded orbeon source code from [git](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms). I have made a war file (with ant orbeon-dist-war) and placed it in tomcat. Everything is working fine. Then I follow the [tutorial](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/orbeon-forms-xforms-tutorial) and make "my-bookcast" application mentioned there.I found the application source code at "/WEB-INF/resources/apps/my-bookcast" and I know which database is used and where the data are saved. But my questions are

1. When I create form using orbeon form builder using the video tutorial mentioned in www.orbeon.com, using mouse and keyboard only where the form saved? How can I see the source code (like "my-bookcast") of the saved form?
2. Can I use the form along with source code in other application, independent off orbeon?

**Update:** Can anyone tell me, if I want to see the data stored in exist-db then how can I do this. I heard about oxygen, which can be used as a exist-db browser. In that case where can I found the exist-db related configuration in orbeon to connect with the built-in exist-db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Out of the box, the form definitions and form data are stored into the embedded eXist database. The source code you can see directly from Form Builder, with "Edit Source".
2. No.

Regarding the question in your update: you can disable the `orbeon-exist-filter` eXist security filter in `web.xml`, then should be able to connect with oXygen either via `exist-xmlrpc-servlet` or `exist-rest-servlet` which is mounted on `/exist/rest/*`.

Answer (score 0):

Graphical view

1. You can find this icon on Right Top.

[image]

After clicking, you will get this popup and that's the source

[image]